# Excel 2003: Averaging every Nth row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 2003 and am trying to average every two rows of data in one column,
starting from A1 and ending in A4, for example,

```
1 
2 
1 
2
```

I try to do this average on the B1 column/row as follows (based on [this info](https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/toms-tutorials-for-excel-summing-every-nth-cell/))

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A4),2)=0,A1:A4))
```

However, when doing the above, B1 returns a 0, even though I intended to get a 1.
What would be the best way to make this kind of averaging work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the question was as follows:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A4)-1,2)=0,A1:A4))}
```

where the {} appears after pressing [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)+[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) due to it being an array formula (cannot type that in manually).
The `-1` is the offset based on where the data starts, and depending on the modulus operation, since `MOD(ROW(A1),2)` was 1,

i.e.: if my data instead started on `A27`, and I instead wanted to average values in every 4 rows, then `MOD(ROW(A27),4)` would return a 3 and the formula would correspondingly be offset by `-3`.

Comment: Side note: If attempting the same thing in Libreoffice Calc (free excel clone), typing ctrl+shift+enter again on an existing array formula may not work; You may need to either include a change to the formula or add a space character to end of the formula then do ctrl+shift+enter, as per a 2011 bug report: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38014.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A4),2)=0,A1:A4))
```

The above formula is an **array formula**. To finalize it you need to press [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[shift](/questions/tagged/shift)+[enter](/questions/tagged/enter) simultaneously; not just [enter](/questions/tagged/enter). This has also been abbreviated as CSE.

When you do this correctly, excel will wrap the formula in braces (e.g. `{` and `}`) like this:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A4),2)=0,A1:A4))}
```

You do not type these braces in yourself; they are added automatically when a formula is entered as an array formula.

Comment: Thanks, I was typing in my own answer at about the same time. I also found that in addition to your post, there needed to be a `-1` after the `ROW(A1:A4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid array formulas using the below:

```
=IF((INT(ROW()/2)=ROW()/2)=TRUE,AVERAGE((A1,OFFSET(A1,-1,0))),"")
```

**Image:**

[image]